# Jquery on click on a child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with jQuery being triggered on every click anywhere on the `<tr>`,
but in one of the `<td>` elements there is a button, but I can't trigger the click on it, because the click on `<tr>` takes priority, is there a way to make that not happen?

I tried the `event.preventDefault();` function, but it does not do what I want it to.

The code looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myTable .tr").on('click', function() {
    console.log("TR")
  });

  $("$myTable .tr .button").on('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Button")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="tr">
    <td class="button"><button type="button">Click Me!</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `$("$myTable .tr .button").on('click',function()` must be `$("$myTable .tr .button").on('click',function(event)` then `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: Use `event.stopPropagation();` in the button event handler.

Comment: Or use a different selector!

Comment: DO like this:

$(document).ready(function(){

            $("#myTable .tr td").on('click',function(){
                if(!$(this).hasClass('button')){
                   //some code
                }
            });
        });

Comment: The problem here is `$("$myTable .tr .button")` which should be `$("#myTable .tr .button")`

Comment: @chsdk: just gave you the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I try to understand what do you need and i create a simple demo for you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myTable tr").click(function(e) {
    console.log("TR")
  });

  $("#myTable tr .button").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    console.log("Button")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable" width="100%" border="1">
  <tr class="tr">
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="button">Click Me!</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```